# Pattern matching multiple variables

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, tuples

I'm new to F# and haven't seen anywhere how to do the following correctly

```
let fun1 a b =
match a b with
| a + b > 0 -> fun2
| a + b < 0 -> fun3
```

I have to do this with pattern matching—for homework—but I don't know how to do it correctly. I thought I could be use tuples as follows:

```
let fun1 (a,b) =
match (a,b) with
| (a,b) when a + b > 0 -> fun2
| (a,b) when a + b < 0 -> fun3
```

But that doesn't work too. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have the right idea, you just forgot that indentation matters in F#. Adding spaces makes you solution work:

```
let fun1 (a,b) =  
    match (a,b) with
    | (a,b) when a + b > 0 -> fun2
    | (a,b) when a + b < 0 -> fun3
```

This actually patterns matches twice, so we might want to rewrite it:

```
let fun1 t = function 
    | (a,b) when a + b > 0 -> fun2
    | (a,b) when a + b < 0 -> fun3
```

The compiler/interpreter will let this go through, but with a warning:

> warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression.

I'll leave getting rid of that as an exercise :-)

PS. Good of you to be upfront about this being homework.

Comment: Most welcome. Be sure to look also at kvs's answer below which has good points I didn't make.

Answer (score 11):

Søren Debois is correct.  Here are a few other notes:

1. `a` and `b` are already in scope, so you don't need to match against them, you can match against anything:

   ```
   let fun1 (a,b) =
       match () with
       | () when a + b > 0 -> fun2
       | () when a + b < 0 -> fun3
   ```
2. For that reason, an using an if statement might be more idiomatic.
3. You're clearly missing the case when `a + b = 0`; note that the compiler always assumes that a when clause might not cover anything, so you'll still get a warning that some cases may be unhandled even if you add a `| () when a + b = 0 -> ...` case; you'd need to do just `| () -> ...` or `| _ -> ...` instead.
4. There's a built-in shortcut for definitions of the form `let f <pattern> = match <same pattern> with |...`, which is `let f = function |...`.  You'd use it like:

   ```
   let fun1 = function
   | (a,b) when a + b > 0 -> fun2
   | ...
   ```

   Note that now `a` and `b` aren't bound by the function definition, so the idea from my first note doesn't apply and you have to introduce them in the pattern.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me making my code be and look better!

Answer (score 3):

You can add in the match clause:

```
let fun2() = ()
let fun3() = ()
let fun1 a b =
    match (a+b) with
        | res when res > 0 -> fun2
        | res when res < 0 -> fun3
        | _ -> raise (new System.NotImplementedException())
```

Cover all cases of your pattern, as good practice :-)

Comment: Good call matching on the sum instead of the tuple.